# AVAsset has 0 tracks even though video exists and plays fine from the Camera Roll: troubleshooting steps?

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

Our app lets users record and save videos to their Camera Roll. However, we can't seem to play back the videos in an AVPlayer even though the saved videos play back fine from the Camera Roll.

For some reason, a valid video file reports back as having 0 tracks.

Code:

```
func playPreview(videoUrl: NSURL) {
    let asset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(videoUrl) as? AVAsset

    println("\(asset!.tracks.count) tracks found for \(videoUrl)")

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)
    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    player.play()

}
```

The videoUrl we're testing is:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F532DF34-371C-437E-A121-04C532349720/Documents/editedVideo-7325.mp4

The file exists and is 419498 bytes large as you can see from the code and output below.

Given that the file clearly has content, why are the tracks reporting back as 0? Besides checking the number of tracks, what else can we do to troubleshoot?

```
func listFiles() {
    let allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let docsPath = allPaths[0] as! NSString
    if let files = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docsPath as String, error: nil) as? [String] {

        println("Found \(files.count) file(s) in \(docsPath):")

        for filename in files {
            let filePath = docsPath.stringByAppendingFormat("/\(filename)") as String
            var attr = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath, error: nil)
            if let _attr:NSDictionary = attr {
                let fileSize = _attr.fileSize()
                println("\(filename) @ \(fileSize) bytes")
            }
        }
    }
}


Found 11 file(s) in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5809B294-8A54-4506-A79A-F19E7C877A4A/Documents:
editedVideo-2252.mp4 @ 732567 bytes
editedVideo-3582.mp4 @ 728485 bytes
editedVideo-5175.mp4 @ 413897 bytes
editedVideo-5366.mp4 @ 607992 bytes
editedVideo-5459.mp4 @ 350652 bytes
editedVideo-622.mp4 @ 763026 bytes
**editedVideo-7325.mp4 @ 419498 bytes**
editedVideo-7428.mp4 @ 858742 bytes
editedVideo-7948.mp4 @ 923791 bytes
editedVideo-8612.mp4 @ 429463 bytes
editedVideo-9363.mp4 @ 511307 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

The `videoUrl` parameter did not point to the right file.

Use this approach when referencing videos locally:

```
    let filename = "yourvideo.mp4"
    let allDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDir = allDirs[0] as! NSString
    let filePath = documentsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
```

The `Documents` directory path (e.g., /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8BA180AB-2DD9-4FD8-9312-2BF006914561/Documents/) apparently changes.

You can't expect the same path every time and therefore can't use a fully formed file URL string like we were, even for testing purposes.

The parent directory to the `Documents` directory -- the alphanumeric string -- is what changes.

Answer (score 0):

The NSURL can mean two different things :

1. The absolute file path that you mentioned i.e. starting with file://
2. The URL that you get from ALAsset. You can get it using :

NSURL *asseturl = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL];

where "asset" is of type ALAsset

This URL can then be used to get AVAsset using :

AVAsset.assetWithURL

Please try the second method.